# Define Dictionary of Dictionary in VB

Tags: vb.net

In my VB code I am declaring my variable as below

```
Private m_IntegrationsAttribute As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String)) From {{"PrimeKey", {{"SubKey", ""}}}}
```

But I am getting error message as "Error    205 Value of type '2-dimensional array of String' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)"

Can somebody suggest correct way of declaring variable for dictionary of dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
private m_IntegrationsAttribute As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String)) From 
{
    {"PrimeKey", New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"SubKey", ""}}}
}
```

If you don't use the extra `New Dictionary(Of String, String) From ...` the compiler will interpred `{{"SubKey", ""}}` as `String(,)` because it's the array initializer syntax. That's what the compiler error tells you.